# Cookies not working on mobile browsers (using ASP.NET MVC )

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an ASP.NET C# MVC4 Web site that I have working wonderfully for the most part. However, when we tested on mobile, the cookies that I am using for authentication would not work. I set the Auth cookie in my controller action but when trying to access them on the next call they are not there. Once again this is ONLY A PROBLEM ON MOBILE. Works fine in desktop versions of IE, Chrome and Firefox. Does not work with Chrome on Android.

Code to write cookie (in controller action):

```
    //Set information into object that can be read out of the cookie later
    FormsAuthModel UserDataObj = new FormsAuthModel
    {
        UserID = dmUser.ID,
        PasswordChange = dmUser.PasswordChange
    };
    string UserData = Convert.ToBase64String(clsShared.Serialize(UserDataObj));

    //Create the ticket
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, dmUser.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false, UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    // Encrypt the ticket
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Create the cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Code to read cookie (in Global.asax.cs - Application_PostAuthenticateRequest):

```
    HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        try
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            UserDataObj = (FormsAuthModel)clsShared.Deserialize(Convert.FromBase64String(authTicket.UserData), typeof(FormsAuthModel));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //WriteEvent(string.Format("Error deserializing auth ticket - {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

The AuthCookie is always null on the subsequent requests. What the user sees is a login screen, they fill it out and they get redirected right back to the login screen.

I could not find anything in my searches that helped explain why all the mobile requests (my phone, my tablet and other users' phones) would act differently than the desktop browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

OK I found a solution although I am not sure why. I changed the cookie creation code as follows and it worked.

```
    //Set information into object that can be read out of the cookie later
    FormsAuthModel UserDataObj = new FormsAuthModel
    {
        UserID = dmUser.ID,
        PasswordChange = dmUser.PasswordChange
    };
    string UserData = Convert.ToBase64String(clsShared.Serialize(UserDataObj));

    //Create the ticket
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, dmUser.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false, UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    // Encrypt the ticket
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Create the cookie - FIX IS HERE!!!
    Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value = encTicket;
    //HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
    //Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Notice that the only change is in adding the cookie by setting the value directly instead of creating a cookie object and adding that to the collection.

i.e. - **Response.Cookies["Name"] = Value;**

I got the idea from this MS article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx.

So does anyone know why this would make a difference? I have used the cookie instance method several times before and never had this problem.